# Excel and Microsoft Date Code Conversion

Tags: excel

How do I convert this (69.36) into a representation of how many Months, Days, Hours ,Minutes & seconds?

Comment: That depends heavily on what it represents.

Comment: What do you mean @minitech?

Comment: You also need to consider that **MONTH** represents a variable length of time.

Comment: @Zornjac 69.36 what?  eagles? parsecs? stars? decades? centuries? gravitons? feet? hours? minutes? days? seconds? etc.

Comment: Sorry @RonRosenfeld, I thought I specified that in my question.

Comment: @Zornjac I must be missing it because I do not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:
Sorry, there are a still a few more cases the code in update 1 won't match. I have two suggestions, one is easy but only does days, hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
=FLOOR(B4-A4,1)&":"&TEXT((B4-A4)-FLOOR(B4-A4,1),"hh:mm:ss")
```

But the request above wants months which is really tricky with the built in date functions because months are not the same length in days. As before, I have a two cell solution which is ugly and long but appears to work in more cases:

Store: in c1

```
=12*(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))+(MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1))+IF(DAY(B1)-DAY(A1)+IF(FLOOR(B1,1)<FLOOR(A1,1),-1,0)<0,-1,0)
```

Final solution formula

```
=FLOOR(C1/12,1)&":"&MOD(C1,12)&":"&FLOOR(B1-DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+C1,DAY(A1)),1)&":"&TEXT((B1-A1)-FLOOR(B1-A1,1),"hh:mm:sss")
```

Results:

```
A               B               C           Result      Simple Days + Time Formula
5/1/2006 0:00   5/2/2007 0:00   12  1:0:1:00:00:00      366:00:00:00
5/1/2006 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  12  1:0:1:04:55:00      366:04:55:00
5/1/2007 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  0   0:0:1:04:55:00      1:04:55:00
5/2/2007 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  0   0:0:0:04:55:00      0:04:55:00
5/2/2006 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  12  1:0:0:04:55:00      365:04:55:00
5/2/2005 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  24  2:0:0:04:55:00      730:04:55:00
5/1/2006 18:30  5/2/2007 15:30  12  1:0:1:21:00:00      365:21:00:00
5/1/2006 17:35  5/2/2007 15:30  12  1:0:1:21:55:00      365:21:55:00
4/25/2007 17:35 5/2/2007 15:30  0   0:0:7:21:55:00      6:21:55:00
5/7/2006 18:30  5/2/2007 15:30  11  0:11:25:21:00:00    359:21:00:00
```

Those last two rows failed to deliver a correct result in the last update's formula.

Update 1:
There is a problem with the way that old formula I gave handles dates in different months. Something odd happens in counting the months. No idea why. Again consider a two times in A1 (1/1/2006  10:35:00 AM) and B1 (5/2/2007  3:30:00 PM). Then in c1 you want the following formula to calculate a date with the month and year from b1 at the same time and day as a1:

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),DAY(A1))+TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

Then the (much uglier) formula to solve the problem is:

```
=IF(C1-A1>0,TEXT(C1-A1,"yy:mm")&":"&TEXT(B1-C1,"dd:hh:mm:ss"),"00:00:"&TEXT(B1-A1,"dd:hh:mm:ss"))
```

I haven't testing it exhaustively but I tested a number of cases and it seems to work.

```
A               B               C           Result
5/1/2006 0:00   5/2/2007 0:00   5/1/2007    00:12:01:00:00:00
5/1/2006 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  5/1/2007    00:12:01:04:55:00
5/1/2007 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  5/1/2007    00:00:01:04:55:00
5/2/2007 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  5/2/2007    00:00:00:04:55:00
5/2/2006 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  5/2/2007    00:12:00:04:55:00
5/2/2005 10:35  5/2/2007 15:30  5/2/2007    01:12:00:04:55:00
```

NB: no error checking in case the date in B is greater than A, in which case gives a "#VALUE!" error.

---

Old Version 
Say that A1 contains date 1 5/9/2007 10:35 and B1 contains date 2 6/9/2007 15:30
then this is the difference in time:

```
=TEXT(B1-A1,"m:d:h:mm:ss")
```

Which gives the desired result

```
1:31:4:55:00
```